# About assignment operator over loading error

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Please explain the error message for this program ..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class copyConst
{

    private:
    int someVal;
    public:
    copyConst(const copyConst &objParam)
    {
        someVal = objParam.someVal;
    }
    copyConst()
    {
        someVal = 9;
    }
    copyConst& operator=(const copyConst &objParam)
    {
        if (this == &objParam)
            return *this;

        someVal = objParam.someVal;
        return *this;
        }
    };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    copyConst obj1;
    copyConst obj2(obj1);
    copyConst obj3 = obj1;
    copyConst obj4;
    obj4 = obj1;


    return 0;
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> gcc -Wall -o "untitled" "untitled.cpp" (in directory:
>   /home/rwik/Documents) untitled.cpp: In function ‘int main(int,
>   char**)’: untitled.cpp:53:12: warning: variable ‘obj3’ set but not
>   used [-Wunused-but-set-variable] /tmp/ccUIyRPg.o: In function
>   `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   untitled.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to`
>   std::ios_base::Init::Init()' untitled.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined
>   reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' Compilation failed.
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two type of warning messages. The second one is because of missing linking flag in gcc:
`gcc -lstdc++ -Wall -o "untitled" "untitled.cpp"` (or the equivalent `g++ -Wall -o "untitled" "untitled.cpp`.

The first warning regarding unused variable is because of `obj3` variable which is declared but not used anywhere else. For such cases I'm using `(void)obj3;` statement to workaround such warning messages.

Answer (score 1):

Compile using `g++`, not `gcc`. You have C++ code, not C code.

It has nothing to do with the class code.

Comment: Strange downvote, the answer is completely correct! +1 to compensate.